# Where are the file templates in Android Studio 4.1 located?

Tags: android, android-studio, file-templates

I have trouble importing my custom file templates into **Android Studio 4.1 Canary 5**. In prior versions of Android Studio (up to 4.0) I used to copy my templates into

`<Android Studio Installation>/Contents/plugins/android/lib/templates` (I am using Mac)

But in 4.1, there are no templates there and when I copy mine there, they seem to be ignored.

Has anyone faced the same issue?

Thank you!

Comment: any updates on this issue

Comment: Still nothing.. I'm losing so much time since this feature is gone :-/

Comment: I was afraid to update android studio because of problems might occur like that and now my hands are tied. Google becoming more evil company year by year

Answer (score 17):

Android Studio 4.1 uses a new templating API which is *visible* but not *public* yet - you can see a sample [here](https://github.com/thagikura/AndroidTemplatePluginSample), although I haven't been able to get this to work. Unfortunately in the process, Google seem to have removed the old way of adding templates.

For those interested in tracking progress, you can star the issue on Google's issue tracker system [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154531807).

Answer (score 3):

### For android studio 4.1 I found the live templates XML in this below path:

> IDE configuration directory changes The locations of user
> configuration directories have been changed to the following:
>
> Windows Syntax: %APPDATA%\Google<product>
>
> Example: C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1
>
> macOS Syntax: ~/Library/Application Support/Google/
>
> Example: ~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1
>
> Linux Syntax: ~/.config/Google/
>
> Example: ~/.config/Google/AndroidStudio4.1

**C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\templates**

Comment: inside the relevant example folder, there should be a directory called `fileTemplates` (create it if its missing), place your templates inside.

Answer (score 0):

For android studio `4.1` I found the live templates XML in this below path:

> ~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/settingsRepository/repository/templates

This is for Mac OS

Answer (score -5):

File > Settings> File and Code templates> press + icon to add new template