# Where can I put my custom template in Android Studio 4.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-4.1

In elder version of Android studio, I put it in `../plugins/android/lib/templates/other` folder. But when I update to version 4.1, my folder is cleared. I've tried initializing a new one but it didn't work.

Comment: check if the folder is not being cleared by any gradle file

Comment: Custom templates were always removed when updating android studio. It alwais was a annoing problem for me.
But since AS4.1 they change templating API. See this issue:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61138322/where-are-the-file-templates-in-android-studio-4-1-located

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67081259/3806413

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio 4.1 changed configuration directory:

> Windows Syntax: %APPDATA%\Google<product>
>
> Example: C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1
>
> macOS Syntax: ~/Library/Application Support/Google/
>
> Example: ~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1
>
> Linux Syntax: ~/.config/Google/
>
> Example: ~/.config/Google/AndroidStudio4.1

check it out [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases#directory-configuration-changes)

Comment: There isnt a template folder there either and when I tried to re-create the structure then it didnt work. Can you explain the next steps you took?

Comment: I gave a workaround here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65171902/how-to-add-new-live-templates-in-android-studio-in-ubuntu/66382743#66382743